# Remove character from enite dataframe in R with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame that has many columns and many rows

```
col_1 | col_2 | ... | col_n
---------------------------    
val_1 | val_2 | ... | val_n
val_1 | val_2 | ... | val_n
  .   |   .   |  .  |   . 
  .   |   .   |  .  |   . 
  .   |   .   |  .  |   . 
val_1 | val_2 | ... | val_n
```

My wish is to remove all commas `,` from all values with tidyverse.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(columnValues) {return(gsub(",","",columnValues))})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_remove_all` and this should comply with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
          mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all, ","))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `gsub` to replace commas and `across` to apply it for multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~gsub(',', '', ., fixed = TRUE)))
```

Or in base R -

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub(',', '', x, fixed = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `gsub`

```
list2DF(lapply(df, function(v) gsub(",", "", v)))
```